# Set default value of dropdown through grails paramater

Tags: grails, parameters

I send a user to a page with setting the parameters using JS like this:

```
 window.location='/myPgae/MyController?terminId='+terminId;
```

On the view page I want to set the dafult value of one drop-down menu from the parameter if it was sent.

Drop down:

```
<select name="terminId" dojoType="dijit.form.Select" style="width:180px;">
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="3">Option 3 Tage</option>
        </select>
```

If parameter was sent I want to set option3 as the selected value. I know there is an option `selected="selected"` but how can I do the check?

Answer (score 1):

I've got it:

```
<g:if test="${params.terminId}">
            <option value="option3" selected="option3">option3</option>
          </g:if>
          <g:else>
            <option value="option3">option3</option>
         </g:else>
```